# Outlook and Thunderbird do not receive attachment when I send from Python using Mime

Tags: python, email, pdf, outlook, thunderbird

I was trying to send an email with attachment using MimeBase in python. I can even send the email and receive the pdf attachment when I'm not using Thunderbird or Outlook and open the mailbox in the browser.

```
mensagem = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
mensagem['Subject'] = Header(sTituloEmail.encode('utf-8'), 'UTF-8').encode()
mensagem['To'] = Header(sEmailTo.encode('utf-8'), 'UTF-8').encode()
mensagem['CC'] = Header(sEmailCC.encode('utf-8'), 'UTF-8').encode()
mensagem['From'] = Header(sEmailFrom.encode('utf-8'), 'UTF-8').encode()

# Corpo da mensagem
mensagem.attach(MIMEText(sTextEmail.encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'UTF-8'))

## Arquivos anexos.
mime = MIMEBase('application', 'x-pdf') #I've used pdf too and did the same thing
mime.set_payload(open('out.pdf', 'rb').read())
encoders.encode_base64(mime)
mime.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename('out.pdf'))
mensagem.attach(mime)
```

Comment: Can you add the raw message as you see it in Thunderbird?

Comment: I do not receive the attachment, only the email body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your email is `mensagem = MIMEMultipart('mixed')`
and  try `mime = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")`.

If that will not help, share you complete code.

Comment: The problem could be happening becouse of MIMEMultipart? And when i've changed from x-pdf to octet-stream nothing had changed

Comment: When I changed from alternative to mixed the MIMEMultipart it worked. Thanks Maurice!